# extending Cloudflare hosted security to the not-cloudflare resources

Tags: dns, cloudflare, firebase-hosting, cloudflare-workers, cloudflare-apps

Halo, i’m a dev recently diving into cloudflare security layers and got few questions on a website security which is deployed to cloudflare. I’m using Pages and my domain is directly hosted by cloudflare Registrar. I’m also using the security layers provided with cloudflare infrastructure, including [ Bots, DDos, Settings, Page Shield ], which can be found in security tab of my domain in cloudflare dashboard. Below list is my questions:

security layers in use: `[ Bots, DDos, Settings, Page Shield ]`

1. I’m using firebase hosting to link my firebase functions with the domain which is hosted by cloudflare. In this case, do the above listed security layers of cloudflare automatically protect the firebase hosting resources or traffics?
2. I’m using cloudflare workers to manage Durable Objects. The Workers’ functions are also linked to the same root domain with different subdomain. In this case, do the above listed security layers of cloudflare automatically protect the Worker traffics?

- the proxy status of firebase hosting connection is “DNS only” mode(not “Proxied” mode), since in the case of Proxied, the dns connection does not work(i didn't figure out the reason yet..). In this case, it makes me feel like the firebase hosting resources are not being protected since the orange switch in DNS dash is turned off
- please consider the cloudflare plan is Pro

Thank you in advance [:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the products you are listing, Cloudflare is implemented as a reverse proxy.

This means that from an end user perspective, when they try to connect to your services, their traffic reaches Cloudflare first (since a proxied record resolves to a Cloudflare anycast IP). Cloudflare carries out the features and security services that are configured, then forwards the HTTP requests to your origin infrastructure as specified in your Cloudflare DNS tab. This is true when the traffic is directed to proxied records.

For records in DNS-only mode, Cloudflare only performs DNS resolution (answering to the DNS query for that DNS record). Once this is done, the client will connect directly to the specified resource and the traffic will not be flowing through the Cloudflare network, meaning Cloudflare cannot provide proxy services in this scenario.

For a full explanation, I recommend the following [documentation page](https://developers.cloudflare.com/dns/manage-dns-records/reference/proxied-dns-records/)

Comment: This is awesome answer Paolo! Thank you for the documentation also [: